# Error in Weibull distribution

Tags: plot, gnuplot, weibull

file.data has the following values to fit with Weibull distribution,

```
x       y 
2.53    0.00
0.70    0.99
0.60    2.45
0.49    5.36
0.40    9.31
0.31    18.53
0.22    30.24
0.11    42.23
```

Following the Weibull distribution function `f(x)=1.0-exp(-lambda*x**n)`, it is giving error:

```
fit f(x) 'data.dat' via lambda, n
```

and finally plotting f(x) and xy graph have large discrepancy.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. You must skip the first line (if it really is `x y`).
2. You must use the correct function (the pdf and not the CDF, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution, like you did in https://stackoverflow.com/q/20336051/2604213)
3. You must use an additional scaling parameter, because your data are not normalized
4. You must select adequate initial values for the fitting.

The following works fine:

```
f(x) = (x < 0 ? 0 : a*(x/lambda)**(n-1)*exp(-(x/lambda)**n))
n = 0.5
a = 100
lambda = 0.15
fit f(x) 'data.dat' every ::1 via lambda, n, a

set encoding utf8
plot f(x) title sprintf('λ = %.2f, n = %.2f', lambda, n), 'data.dat' every ::1
```

That gives (with 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: 1. my file has multiple columns but {fit f(x) 'data.dat' u 4:($7) via lambda, n, a} did not work, 2. Thanks for the link, 3. How did you conclude additional parameter a = 100?, and 4. How did you make the right guess for n, a, and lambda? Many many thanks!

Comment: How did you do "half" pdf? I am always having "full bell shape" @Christoph

Comment: I used another parameter `a`, because your data is not normalized. I just played around with `a`, `lambda` and `n` to get close enough so that `fit` can work. The Weibull-distribution is defined only for positive `x`-values. The distinction is done inside `f(x)` with the check `(x < 0 ? ... : ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you do the half plot? I am always having full bell shape. :/

Comment: I used exactly the script shown in the answer with version 4.6.4. and `set terminal pngcairo size 600,400; set output 'foo.png'`.

Comment: Oh I guess output.png shows the rendered half. On screen without output shows a full shape. Thanks!

Comment: No, that doesn't depend on the terminal, I see the same behaviour with `wxt` and version 4.2.6, 4.4.4, 4.6.4 and 4.7 (development version). Put a `reset` at the start of the script to exclude effects of previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the actual command you provided to gnuplot, it won't work because you haven't yet defined f(x).

Comment: Oh I actually defined cdf instead of pdf as Christoph mentioned. Thanks Lee.